# No respose on buttons after starting another activity Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

The Error is like this:
1. The code works previously, but not now even i commented them out.
2. What i am doing is to Login from the LoginActivity, and then start the MainActivity by intent
3. After starting the MainActivity its buttons have no response, even with the prebuilt ones
4. Checked the Profiler, can sense Touch Event

The Logcat shows no errors in red but only NoClassDefFoundError
Cleaned the project a few times, also tried Invalidate Caches / Restart but didn't solve the problem

Comment: check if you have added activity in manifest. Do provide a code for what you are doing on button click, activity, manifest etc

Comment: check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/5756989#5756989

Comment: checked, but what else should i do other than rebuild and invalidate caches and restart?

Answer (score 0):

Seems found the problem. The ListView overlaps all the buttons. Thanks all.